# Identifying high load sql

Tags: oracle, performance, monitoring

We had an oracle outage some days ago. 
We have inbetween awr tools. I genarated  awrrpt report but dont see anything suspicious.
Which report should I generate to see sql, which caused very high cpu load?

Comment: Why do you believe that there was a SQL statement that "caused very high CPU load"?  If your snapshot interval is sufficiently small and your AWR report is sufficiently localized and there was a SQL statement in that interval that was consuming a large amount of CPU, it should be on the AWR report (and the top wait events should include significant CPU waits).  If you're not seeing that, either your theory that there was a rogue SQL statement was incorrect, your AWR report is insufficiently localized, or you're reading the AWR report incorrectly.

Comment: Have you checked the alert log to find out what caused the outage?

Comment: You may want to start by looking at the alert log for the time that it was slow, in case there is something there.